# IdeaVim and russian layout

Tags: vim, keyboard-layout, ideavim

Is there any way to make IdeaVim understand russian layout in modes other than Input? In my .vimrc I have

```
set keymap=russian-jcukenwin
```

so I can switch languages in VIM by pressing Ctrl+^ and relatively happy with that. But it seems that IdeaVim doesn't read or understand this setting. It can be very annoying to stop typing something (for example comment) in russian, switch to command mode and stuck. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First i tried to use `langmap` like in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sigsergv/5329458) but IdeaVim does not support `langmap`.

Next I tried to use `map` so I made this solution:

```
let rumap = 'йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэёячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ'
let enmap = 'qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;''\zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>' 
let mapLen = strchars(rumap)
let i = 0
while i < mapLen
    let ruChar = matchstr(rumap, ".", byteidx(rumap, i))
    let enChar = enmap[i]
    "echo 'map '.ruChar.' '.enChar
    execute 'map '.ruChar.' '.enChar
    execute 'cmap '.ruChar.' '.enChar
    let i += 1
endwhile

map Ё \|
cmap Ё \|
```

You can customize it for your keyboard layout.

But I forgot that IdeaVim does not support vimscript and `cmap` and I added `echo 'map '.ruChar.' '.enChar` (commented line), appended code from above to `.vimrc` and opened vim from command line so it printed me all `map` commands. I added them to `.ideavimrc` and appended mapping of pipe (|) character:

```
map й q
map ц w
map у e
map к r
map е t
map н y
map г u
map ш i
map щ o
map з p
map х [
map ъ ]
map ф a
map ы s
map в d
map а f
map п g
map р h
map о j
map л k
map д l
map ж ;
map э '
map ё \
map я z
map ч x
map с c
map м v
map и b
map т n
map ь m
map б ,
map ю .
map Й Q
map Ц W
map У E
map К R
map Е T
map Н Y
map Г U
map Ш I
map Щ O
map З P
map Х {
map Ъ }
map Ф A
map Ы S
map В D
map А F
map П G
map Р H
map О J
map Л K
map Д L
map Ж :
map Э "
map Я Z
map Ч X
map С C
map М V
map И B
map Т N
map Ь M
map Б <
map Ю >
map Ё /|
```

Now I have IdeaVim working with cyrillic layout in normal, visual+select and operator-pending modes.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me! Well, almost.
I realized that combinations like `ciw` or `daw` still do not work. Looks like `i` and `a` are not handled correctly when used as 'inside' and 'around'. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: These combinations do not work for me too :( I've not found solution yet. If you will then please post it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd added that the encoding should be ANSI

Answer (score 3):

You can install [Fcitx](https://github.com/fcitx/fcitx) and [IdeaVimExtension](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9615-ideavimextension).

Add the following line to your `~/.ideavimrc`:

```
set keep-english-in-normal-and-restore-in-insert
```

IDE will switch to English in normal mode and restore the previous input language in insert mode.

Installing and configuring Fcitx on Ubuntu Gnome ([Fcitx - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fcitx)):

1. Install with `sudo apt install fcitx`
2. Create `~/.pam_environment` file with the following contents:

```
XMODIFIERS DEFAULT=@im=fcitx
GTK_IM_MODULE DEFAULT=fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE DEFAULT=fcitx
```

3. Add a startup application:

[image: fcitx startup program]

4. Install [Input Method Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/261/kimpanel/) Gnome extension.

For Vim you may want to install [fcitx.vim](https://github.com/lilydjwg/fcitx.vim) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Привіт! The short answer is no, there is no workaround. Unless you are willing modify IdeaVim.

When a key is pressed, one can get different information about the event. For our case, the most interesting pieces are `hardware key code`, and `key value`. The former is identical for <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>ы</kbd>, and <kbd>і</kbd>, which are located on the same key; the latter differs from layout to layout. Since IdeaVim [uses key values](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getkeychar&type=Code) for bindings (and in the settings actions are also bound to key values), it isn't possible to trigger actions while using a layout where the key value is different. As a consequence, it will work well in a German layout, for example.

I would recommend you to avoid writing comments in Russian anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Problem on **Windows**.

Your .ideavimrc file has to be same encoding as your project files.

In my case IdeaVim created .ideavimrc with windows-1251 encoding when my project files was with UTF-8. And config wasn't working. I changed encoding, reloaded Rider and it has finally applied.